# How can I create a swap file?

Tags: linux, swap

I know how to create and use a swap partition but can I also use a file instead?

How can I create a swap file on a Linux system?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's start with the basic information, you should inspect what [`vm.swappiness`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) is set, and if set wisely to a more acceptable value than 60, which is the default, you should have no problem. This command can be run as normal user:

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
```

For instance, I have 32GB RAM server with 32GB swap file with [`vm.swappiness`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) = 1. Quoting the Wikipedia:

> [`vm.swappiness`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) = 1: Kernel version 3.5 and over, as well as Red Hat kernel version 2.6.32-303 and over: Minimum amount of swapping without disabling it entirely.

---

In this example, we create a swap file:

- 8GB in size,
- Located in `/` (the root directory).

Change these two things accordingly to your needs.

1. Open terminal and become [`root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) ([`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))); if you have [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) enabled, you may also do for example `sudo -i`; see [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for all options):

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
2. Allocate space for the swap file:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
   ```

Optionally, if your system supports it, you may add `status=progress` to that command line.

Note, that the size specified here in `G` is in GiB (multiples of 1024).

3. Change permissions of the swap file, so that only [`root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) can access it:

   ```
   chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```
4. Make this file a swap file:

   ```
   mkswap /swapfile
   ```
5. Enable the swap file:

   ```
   swapon /swapfile
   ```
6. Verify, whether the swap file is in use:

   ```
   cat /proc/swaps
   ```
7. Open a text editor you are skilled in with this file, e.g. [`nano`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) if unsure:

   ```
   nano /etc/fstab
   ```
8. To make this swap file available after reboot, add the following line:

   ```
   /swapfile        none        swap        sw        0        0
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Editor's note: Step 1 and Step 2 are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the script for creating a SWAP Memory of 16GB:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#find Free
free -h
#Checking availability space
df -h
#swap Off
sudo swapoff /swapfile
#Allocate swap
sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile
#correct amount of space was reserved
ls -lh /swapfile
#file only accessible to root
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
#amount of space was reserved for the root
ls -lh /swapfile
#now mark the file as swap space
sudo mkswap /swapfile
#Swap On
sudo swapon /swapfile
#swap Show
sudo swapon --show
#statment 
echo -e "\n\n Swap 16Gb done"

exit 0
```