# How to check mdadm software RAID array, if the e.g. the swap file is on it?

Tags: alias, mdadm, software-raid, integrity

I am on Linux Mint 18.1 with 4.8 kernel.

Question is: How to check ([`mdadm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm)) [software RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Software-based) array, if the e.g. the [swap file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238784/126755) is on it?

I need the correct procedure before and after calling the `checkarray` script to define proper alias.

Comment: You just do. No need to swapoff or umount. Not sure what gives you that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example the array is called `md0` and it's mounted in `/raid1`.

---

**Check array alias:**

1. Supposing a swap file is located on the array, we need to turn it off first. If that is the only swap area on the system, we can do:

   ```
   sudo swapoff --all
   ```
2. The array needs to be unmounted in order for it to be checked properly:

   ```
   sudo umount /raid1
   ```
3. After this preparation took place, we may call the `checkarray` script, I chose fast priority, but you may choose any priority option:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --fast /dev/md0
   ```
4. If you wish to watch the progress of the array check every second:

   ```
   watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat
   ```

---

So the complete [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) check array [`alias`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)#Unix) located e.g. in your personal `.bash_aliases` file would look something like:

```
alias checkarray='sudo swapoff --all && \
                  sudo umount /raid1 && \
                  sudo /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --fast /dev/md0 && \
                  watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat'
```

Make sure you close all open files on the array before calling it.

---

**After-Check array alias:**

I think no further comments needed:

```
alias checkarray-after='sudo mount /dev/md0 /raid1 && \
                        sudo swapon --all'
```