# Debian - move swap-space to different directory

Tags: linux, debian, partition, swap

I installed a debian distribution and by mistake created a swap partition with the size of 3MB instead of 3GB. As one can imagine the system is not running very smooth, as soon as enough memory is used (some opened tabs in the web-browser etc.) the hard-drive starts to work like crazy and the whole system almost freezes.

To temporarily work around a proper solution and resize this partition to an appropriate amount of gigabytes, is there a way to move the swap space for an example to the users `$HOME` directory?

Comment: You can try `swapoff`, delete `swap`, recreate `swap` with the intended size, update `fstab`.

Comment: You can create a swap file, using the instructions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238783/how-can-i-create-a-swap-file