# Extend 100GB of unallocated space on /dev/sda1 device in command line

Tags: debian, partition, ext4, disk, cfdisk

I'm looking on my Debian 11 Server for the easiest way to allocate 100GB of extra space after the /dev/sda1 device in command line.

The sda1 partition is almost full and needs to be resize with the unallocated space.

Here is the structure of my hard drive:

```
Disk: /dev/sda
                                                                     Size: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
                                                                              Label: dos, identifier: 0xea1313af

    Device                    Boot                                 Start                     End                 Sectors                Size              Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1                 *                                     2048               192940031               192937984                 92G              83 Linux                                
   /dev/sda2                                                   192942078               209713151                16771074                  8G               5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                                                192942080               209713151                16771072                  8G              82 Linux swap / Solaris
    Free space                                                 209713152               419430399               209717248                100G

Partition type: Linux (83)                                                                                                                                                               │
 │     Attributes: 80                                                                                                                                                                       │
 │Filesystem UUID: b4804667-c4f3-4915-a95d-d3b83fac302c                                                                                                                                     │
 │     Filesystem: ext4                                                                                                                                                                     │
 │     Mountpoint: / (mounted)
```

Could you help me to easily achieve this in command line? Thanks!
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free space is not directly after the `sda1` partition so you can't use it, you need to remove (or move, but removing is easier) the swap partition `sda5`.

1. Stop the swap using `swapoff /dev/sda5`
2. Remove the `sda5` partition and the `sda2` extended partition.
3. Resize the `sda1` partition. Don't forget to resize the filesystem too using `resize2fs`. You can check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-to-expand-ext4-partition-size-using-command-line/67107) for more details about resizing partitions using `fdisk`.
4. Create a new swap partition (optionally a logical one inside a new extended partition if you want setup similar to your current one).
5. Update your `/etc/fstab` swap record with the new partition number or UUID.

Comment: *Backups first!* Booting from a LiveCD second!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it with a [live ISO CD from GParted](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/):

```
Disk: /dev/sda
Size: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Label: dos, identifier: 0xea1313af

 Device                          Boot                                           Start                          End                      Sectors                      Size                    Id Type

  /dev/sda1                       *                                               2048                      393215999                    393213952                    187.5G                    83 Linux
  /dev/sda2                                                                    393216000                    419430399                 26214400                     12.5G                     5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                                                                393218048                    419428351                     26210304                          12.5G                    82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Victor